# editable Grid view in CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to make editable Grid view in CRM 2013. I am new to CRM 2013.
I have made code of Editable Grid view using jqgrid using JQuery. Now, How can I relate/Integrate this code in CRM 2013 to make CRM Grid editable?

**JQuery Code :**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Exmple</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        var mydata = [{
            name: "Toronto",
            country: "Canada",
            continent: "North America"
        }, {
            name: "New York City",
            country: "USA",
            continent: "North America"
        }, {
            name: "Silicon Valley",
            country: "USA",
            continent: "North America"
        }, {
            name: "Paris",
            country: "France",
            continent: "Europe"
        }]
$("#grid").jqGrid({
            data: mydata,
            datatype: "local",
            colNames: ["Name", "Country", "Continent"],
            colModel: [{
                name: 'name',
                index: 'name',
                editable: true,
            }, {
                name: 'country',
                index: 'country',
                editable: true,
            }, {
                name: 'continent',
                index: 'continent',
                editable: true,
            }],
            pager: '#pager',
            'cellEdit': true,
            'cellsubmit': 'clientArray',
            editurl: 'clientArray'
        });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table id="grid"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you want this grid to be populated by CRM, and then save to CRM once changes have been made, correct?

Comment: yes,absolutely correct. Have you any solution for this? Which steps I need to follow.

Answer (score 1):

To make grid working you should implement following:
1. Code that will read information from CRM to show information that is already inside CRM.
2. Code that will create/update/delete information in CRM.

I would suggest you to use on of frameworks to implement CRUD operations. I use [XrmSvcToolkit](http://xrmsvctoolkit.codeplex.com/).